# How do I allow my app to have tracks dropped into it

Tags: spotify

At present when am dragging a track in spotify over the app it doesn't allow dropping. However, the last.fm and moodagent apps do allow this. What code should I be including to make this possible?

I assume it's something to do with `EVENTS.LINKSCHANGED` but including it doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 3):

You need to include the `AcceptedLinkTypes` key in your manifest.json file. See the [documentation](http://developer.spotify.com/download/spotify-apps-api/guidelines/#applicationmanifest) for details.